# In an implementation of IAuthenticationTokenProvider should you error on Receiving an invalid RefreshToken?

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0

I have an implementation of the IAuthenticationTokenProvider which I'm using in my OAuth server for dealing with refresh tokens. In the method that receives a refresh token I recall the token from my store via the hashed ID. If I am successful on my recall, then I set the context on the caller from my store, however if I'm unsuccessful in the recall, this suggests that it has expired or the token is removed and I'm not sure what I should do in this instance. Is it bad form to tell the caller the reason for the failure?

```
public async Task ReceiveAsync(AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext context)
{
     ...
     var hashedTokenId = _hashingService.CreateHash(context.Token);
     var refreshToken = await workUnit.RefreshTokens.GetByIdAsync(hashedTokenId);

     if (refreshToken != null)
     {
         context.DeserializeTicket(refreshToken.ProtectedTicket);
         await workUnit.RefreshTokens.RemoveByIdAsync(hashedTokenId);
         await workUnit.SaveChangesAsync();
     }
     // else? what should I do here? nothing? OK 200 response?
}
```

Comment: I would probably just tell the client they're unauthorised and leave it at that. The less information an attacker can deduce about your system, the safer you will be.

Comment: .. while the corollary is the less information you give a _client_ about why they can't connect, the more support calls you will get! So what you send with the 401 it depends on who you are expecting to use the service, whether it's public or internal etc.

Comment: .. while the corollary of that is that you should be charging them for support calls so you make more money! :)

Comment: At the moment, it is purely internal use. I've locked down the system best I am able with tight origin limitations and client/secret clients. I've favoured the one use per client/token combination so that if another web client tried to use the same refresh token it would fail. For now at least its all internal and I imagine it would stay that way for a while! I think you may be right to 401 them.